# JS closures for street view API callbacks

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, closures, dom-events

The Google maps API offers some methods that make callbacks to user-written methods but with specific parameters, like `getPanoramaByLocation()`. My problem is that I can't reliably associate my requests with the responses. The basic call looks like:

```
streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation ( latLng, 10, recordPanorama );
```

docs: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StreetViewService

I thought that "with" or a closure would help me pass something to recordPanorama, the callback, other than those two preordained parameters, but I seem only to add the information to the context of `gPBL()`, which of course does not relay it to where it's needed. When I put extra objects into scope with "with", they don't exist in my callback and the arguments passed seem the same.

Trying to match the geographical coordinates of the request with those of the result is not trivial and I think there would be some errors at large intersections. The only other piece of information I have is the time when the request happens; I could tie the queries and responses to each other sort of well by slowing down my requests enough, but isn't there a real way to carry an id to my callback function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to set some variable X and have it persist into the callback function. In that case, you could try putting X in the scope of the closure like so:

```
for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
var x = 10;

magicAjax(URL, function () {
alert(x);
});
}
```

I haven't tested this code; I could be wrong.